# pole target freezes up all the bones in my rig

Tags: rigging, bones, bone.constraints

I was following a guide for rigging and all was fine and working until I add a pole target.

When I do it will freeze up all the bones and I can’t move anything until I remove the pole target.

I have no ideas what to do.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JYTdJUFsAFlBjaP-70cBVp8YbvsZneJz?usp=sharing

Comment: the forearm is where IK modifier is

Comment: Did you add the pole target because I’m the file I didn’t add pole target yet

Comment: Oh yes sorrey. It looks like it has to do with your drivers

Comment: Should I remove the drivers?

Comment: Not sure why it makes the armature freeze but if you remove the driver of the armature (N panel > Object > Transform > Location Y value) it will fix your problem

Comment: Oh okay thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it makes the armature freeze but if you remove the driver of the armature (*N panel > Object > Transform > Location Y* value) it will fix your problem. To remove, right click and *Delete Drivers*:

[image]